# Date validation while typing in input field in Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I have an input text field which will accept date. I need to validate the date if it is not more than one month from today's date.
For example user can't enter after 19th of July,2017. 
How to validate this field.

Note: It is not a datepicker field.

I tried the following code

```
if(new Date(jQuery('#inputDate').val()) > (new Date().getDate()+31)) {
                alert("you are not allowed to select after one month");
                jQuery('#inputDate').val('');}
```

Comment: @ Mathi  did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom `AddDays` Method and use it in if condition like following

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var yourDate = new Date(this.valueOf());
  yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() + days);
  return yourDate;
}

var yourDate= new Date();

$("#inputDate").on("change", function(e){
  // includes current day
  if(new Date($(this).val()) >= yourDate.addDays(30))
  {
      console.log("you are not allowed to select more than month");
      alert("you are not allowed to select more than month");
      $(this).val("");
  }
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="inputDate">
```

Comment: You should clear the input field when it doesn't passes else the value is retained. You can clear it in your function instead of setting it.

Comment: @MilanChheda thanks for information, I have updated my answer

Comment: Nice. You should use `$(this)` instead of creating a new again with `jQuery('#inputDate')`.